# Sql script for parent - child table

Tags: sql, parent-child, recursive-query

I have a table:

```
ID  ParentID
3   1
7   2
4   3
5   4
```

How can I use sql script (recursive way) to list out the result like this:

```
ID  ParentID
3   1
4   3
5   4
7   2
```

Do you have idea?

Comment: Does `Select * from yourtable ORDER BY ID` not work for you?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY ID

Comment: Do you have done any other research to your problem? Google, Manual??

Comment: sorry I mean, obj (ID: 3) has a sub-obj (ID 4), and the obj (ID: 4) has a sub-obj (ID: 5), so I want to list them nearly (from parent to children). Thanks.

Comment: @manh.phi what are you using? MySql, Sql Server, Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY ID` will give you the order you want. But if you want the recursive one:

```
SELECT childs.Id AS 'Child Id', Parents.Id As 'Parent'
FROM YourTable childs
INNER JOIN YourTable parents ON childs.ParentId = parents.Id
ORDER BY Parents.Id
```

Comment: this could be done using this way...exact answer with self join

Comment: That's it, may the Order BY childs.Id, Parents.Id, but definietly this is the good way.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * 
from MyTable 
order By ID;
```

Comment: OP asks a "recursive way", so like CTE in Sql Server. Your solution is not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tablename order by id
```